# How to remove the space between boxes in shiny dashboard (tried other solutions but none would work)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app made with Shiny Dashboard whose layout looks like this (should be reproducible). Now as you can see I removed the space betweeen the boxes vertically (fluid rows), but I didn't want there to be any space between the boxes horizontally (columns) either. However I basically tried everything I found in the other questions referring to similar (but not identical) issues but the horizontal spaces between the boxes stay there quite unimpressed. The following code is what I gave up with, it just used to be ".box {matrgin: 2px;}", which looked absolutely the same as it does now. Can anyone tell be what arguments I have to use to get this done or why the arguments down below won't do the trick?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <-  dashboardBody( tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
.box {margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom:2px;padding:-10px}'
))),
fluidRow(
  box(      title = "Mediennutzung", background = "green", solidHeader = TRUE, height=300
            
  ),
  box(background = "green", title= "Verteilung", height = 300
  )
),

fluidRow(
  box(
    title = "Schlaf", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
    height= 350
  ),
  box(
    title = "Vergleich mit anderen", width = 5, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success"
    , height= 350
  ),
  box(
    title = "Wohlbefinden", width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "success",
    "Ergebnis DASS und PMH, Einordnung, Vergleich mit der Stichprobe", height= 350
  )
),

fluidRow(
  box(
    width = 4, background = "green", title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",
     height= 135
  ),
  box(
    title = "Warum ist das wichtig?", width = 5, background = "green",
     height= 135
  ),
  box(
    title = "Warum ist das wichtig?",width = 3, background = "green",
     height= 135
  )
),

fluidRow(
  box(
    width = 4, background = "green", title= "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",
    "Schlaf mag oder mag nicht mit der Mediennutzung zusammenhngen", height= 125
  ),
  box(
    title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung", width = 5, background = "green",
    "Mal gucken", height= 125
  ),
  box(
    title = "Zusammenhang zur Mediennutzung",width = 3, background = "green",
    "TBC", height= 125
  )
)
)




# here the actual app starts
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Deine Ergebnisse"),
  dashboardSidebar(textInput(inputId = "Code", label= HTML("<b>Willkommen auf unserer Auswertungsseite! Bitte gib hier deinen persÃ¶nlichen Code ein.</b><br><em>(Gross- oder Kleinschreibung ist egal) </em>"), placeholder= "z.B. 01ABAB01"),
                   actionButton (inputId = "Button", label = "Meine Ergebnisse anzeigen"),
                   box(width = 12, background= "blue", HTML(
                     "TEXT"))
  ),
  body)


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your header:

```css
div {padding: 0 !important;}
```

```
body <-  dashboardBody( tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
.box {margin-top: 2px;margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom:2px;padding:-10px}
div {padding: 0 !important;}'
))),
fluidRow(
  box(      title = "Mediennutzung", background = "green", solidHeader = TRUE, height=300
            
  ),
  box(background = "green", title= "Verteilung", height = 300
  )
),
........rest of your app
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the edit. This works fine for the body, but it also affects the sidebar text for some reason (that in the full version of the app is a lot longer and is pushed uncomfortably close to the right edge of the app). Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: Edit: It looks decent if you replace 0 by 2px, but for knowledge's sake it would still be interesting to know why it affects the box in the sidebar panel aswell and how to get rid of this issue (since adding different css to the sidebar box itself didn't change anything).

Comment: @Ninke, it affects the sidebar panel as well because it is targeting all `div` html elements. You can target only the `div` elements inside `.row` divs with: `.row div {padding: 0 !important;}`

Comment: So does the CSS code always refer to the whole document? I assumed that if it was in the body it was only valid for the body.

Comment: @Ninke if you embed your css directly in your file like this, then yes it refers to everything in the file. If you have a separate CSS file you can specify with CSS files you want to apply to each HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Helped me a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help you out!